# in a nextjs-firebase app, google login works locally but not when deployed to Heroku

Tags: firebase, heroku, next.js, firebase-authentication

login modal pops up for a split second and disappears... help anyone?

tried deploying my nextjs-firebase app to Heroku, expected auth to work as it does in dev on localhost

Answer (score 2):

That's because you didn't authorize your production domain given by heroku. you can follow the steps given below to fix it:

- Go to firebase authentication
- click on settings
- then click Authorized domains and add your domain(url) given by heroku.

Answer (score 0):

This can be because of your firebase Auth setup, check if you're not referencing some speicific origin URLs that the Oauth works on. Maybe you're mentioning only the `localhost` origin, but not the domain of the deployed project.